# ServerTags don't work in OnClientClick

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, server-tags

```
<asp:button runat="server" Text="Save as" OnClick="btnSave_click" 
OnClientClick="if(!Check('<% # tb.ClientID %>')) return false; return Object();" 
CausesValidation="false"></asp:button>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb"></asp:TextBox>
```

Server tags don't work here. I spend a 1-2 hours to find some way to make this work, but i didn't find anything.

Server tags works in:

```
<OnClientClick="JSFunc();"

<script type="text/javascript">
    function JSFunc()
    {
         var el = document.getElementById('<% # tb.ClientID %>');
         //some actions with el here
    }
</script>
```

or something others with c#.

Is There no way to make server tags working inline? (first example)

ps. Sorry for the bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an expression builder, you don't need to call databind and you can inline this quite easliy.

see [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

first off in your javascript it should be:

```
<%= tb.ClientID %>
```

Note the "=" sign

Secondly, you will also have to call `DataBind()` Method on your page_load if you wish to do it inline.